# Reading Array and Getting Variable Output

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

By default, Gravity Form merge tags for checkboxes output the value of the selected option. If they choices for a question are English, Spanish, and Other, and the user selects English, the merge tag outputs:

`english`

My end goal is to be able to customize a Gravity Form merge tag output for checkboxes to include all of the options, checkbox-like format, and the selected option (checkbox is checked).

Right now, I'm trying to at least be able to return all of the options. Using this function,

`
add_action( 'gform_pre_submission_3', 'pre_submission_handler' );
function pre_submission_handler( $form ) {

```
foreach($form['fields'] as &$field) {
    if($field['id'] === 13) {
        //$selectData['inputs'] = $field['inputs'];
        $selectData['selections'] = $field['choices'];

        $the_fields = $selectData;

        foreach ($the_fields as $fields) {      

            print_r($fields);       
        }
    }
}
```

I can get an output:

`Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [text] => English 
        [value] => Language: English 
        [isSelected] => 
        [price] => 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [text] => Spanish 
        [value] => Language: Spanish 
        [isSelected] => 
        [price] => 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [text] => Other (specify) 
        [value] => Other 
        [isSelected] => 
        [price] => 
    ) 
)`

**I think that I'm going to need to get the [text] for each of the sub arrays into a new array. What's the syntax like to do that?**

With the new array, I will be able to do a foreach loop, wrapping each element in HTML, using CSS to style the output like a checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shorty:

```
$new_array = array_map(function($a){return $a['text'];},$fields);
```

;)